# php artisan api:routes error: Route is not bound

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dingo-api

i am new into RESTful API in development in Laravel and i just installed Dingo API. When i run the command `php artisan route:list` its giving me the list of routes in the project, when i run `php artisan api:routes` i am getting this error

[image]

I have configured the api.php file probably correctly according to a tutorial i been following and my routes.php file looks like this

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

$api->version('v1', function($api){
    $api->get('hello', function(){
        return 'Heloooooooooooooo';
    });
});
```

when i by-passed that api:routes command and went directly into the browser and hit http://localhost:8000/api/hello, the error it gives me is the one with `status code 500`

```
{"message":"Route is not bound.",
"status_code":500,
"debug":{"line":8614,"file":"C:\\wamp64\\www\\his-word\\his_word_api\\bootstrap\\cache\\compiled.php","class":"LogicException","trace":["#0 C:\\wamp64\\www\\his- ....}
```

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: There is no command called `api:routes` in Laravel. I would also suggest that you run `composer dump-autoload` as well.

Comment: yah there is no command like that, it only comes when u install dingo api, it works

Comment: solved the case though, i reinstalled Laravel and Dingo package, thanks guys